# Reading HL7 data from file and inserting it into the table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mirth

Could someone please help me on capturing the HL7 data into the SQL server using **MIRTHCONNECT**. I was searching for some examples and i was not able to find any tutorials which demonstrates looping through multiple segments. I was able to insert records into the database by going through the tutorials but still i`m stuck in doing the looping process.

Could someone please share me some links or give me some ideas so that i can go through those .

This is my initial thought to loop through each segment since i assume that Mirth connect reads a file line by line.

Thanks for the help

**LOGIC** -(I`m not sure whether this will be the right approach)

```
for each (seg in RAWFILE) {
    if (seg.name().toString() == "MSH") {
       insert into table values ();
    }
   if (seg.name().toString() == "PID") {
       INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES ();
    }
}
```

**sample RAW DATA**

```
MSH|^~&|LAB|CCF|||20040920080937||ORM^O01|42640000 009|P|2.3|
PID|||56797971||RESULTSREVIEW^TESTPATIENT^||196505 25|M||||||||||56797971|
PV1||O|UNKO^|||||
ORC|RE||A0203809||IP|||||||
OBR|1|A0203809|A0203809|400090^Complete Blood Count|||200609240000|||||||200609240847||deleted^^ ^^MD^^^^^^||||||200609241055|||P
OBX|1|ST|40010^White Blood Count (WBC) (x1000)||PENDING||||||P
OBX|2|ST|40020^Red Blood Count (RBC)||PENDING||||||P
ORC|RE||A0203809||CM|||||||
OBR|2|A0203809|A0203809|650300^Depakene (Valproic Acid) Level|||200609240000|||||||200609240847||^deleted^ ^^^MD^^^^^^||||||200609241055|||F
OBX|3|NM|65030^Depakene (Valproic Acid) Level||76.8|ug/ml|50-100||||F|||200609241054||
```

Comment: Each Hl7 Segments will come in separate lines. so you can split the segments line by line and parse the attributes by splitting the segments using '|'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you've got the db insertion working and you're having questions on how to handle repeating segments.  Here is some code that I use in mirth for handling repeating segments.  Of course your milage may vary but this should accomplish what you are wanting.

```
var segCount = 0;

// Loop through message and count number of OBX segments
for each (segment in msg.children()) {
  if(segment.name() === 'OBX') {
    segCount++;
  }
}

// Make changes if there are OBX segments
if (segCount > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < segCount; i++) {
    tmp=msg;

    // Add this segment to the database
   insert into table values ();        

    // Here I am changing each OBX-5.1 to contain normal if OBX-3.1 is 'Some Text'
    if (msg['OBX'][i]['OBX.3']['OBX.3.1'].toString() === 'Some text') {
       tmp['OBX']['OBX.5']['OBX.5.1'] = 'Normal';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to pull the information from an HL7 file and insert into a DB regardless of type.
So, Create one channel with inbound message type as HL7, regardless of you taking HL7 message from file or an open TCP/IP connection.

Go to source, go to transformer, create a JS transformer, supply an HL7 message in the inbound template, and now extract information from the message and store it in variables. Something like below.

`var firstname=msg[PID][PID.5][PID.5.2].toString();`

A helpful tip is to drag and drop the elements from the inbound message template and store in the variable.

Now, move this variable in the channel Map, so that we can capture it in destination.

`channelMap.put('first_name',firstname);`

Now for the second part,
Go to destination of the same channel and create one DB writer that writes information to a DB.

Don't select Use Javascript, instead just write your INSERT query, something like below.

`INSERT INTO PATIENT(first_name) VALUES (channelMap.get('first_name');`

There is whole lot of documentation available at Mirth to help you with the DB writer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you please share me few links